# Verifying quantum states

Tags: quantum-information

Suppose Alice creates a secret n-qubit state $\lvert \psi \rangle$ from a description $d$, and gives the states to Bob. (Bob doesn't know $d$ )

Bob who doesn't trust the channel, wants to verify if the states were indeed prepared by Alice, and not by an eavesdropper, Eve.

Is it possible for Alice to give a proof $P$ such that Bob can verify the authenticity of $\lvert \psi \rangle$,  without revealing to him the description $d$?

(A trivial way would be to just have another state $\lvert \psi' \rangle$ where Bob can perform a swap test and verify, but this would require alice to prepare and store as many states as she sends to Bob, can we be more efficient here?)